# For any vertex A and B and edge E in same biconnected component, is it always possible to have a simple path from A to B passing E?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

While solving some algorithm problems, met a problem using some biconnected component properties.

Assume that vertex A and B are in same biconnected component. And there is edge E(u, v) in that component. Then is it always possible to have a simple path from A to B passing E for any pair of A, B, E(all in same bi-comp)?

I tried to find some counter examples, but failed. Then I tried to prove it using the fact that any pair of vertices in same bi-comp has 2 edge-disjoint paths which is also failed.

Could anybody help me to prove this please?

Comment: did you try the property that any pair of vertices in same bi-comp has 2 vertex-disjoint paths?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic yeah, but doesn't that property ensures that path (a-u) and (v-b) are disjoint?

Comment: for a circle like this, a - v - u - b - d - a , then (a-u) and (v-b) are not disjoint?
I ask the question because vertex-disjoint property should be more powerful than edge-disjoint mentioned in the post

Comment: @PetarPetrovic Thanks for reply, but still don't get it. Lets assume that (a,u) path does not contain v. Then a -> u -> v -> b might be possible but the 'vertex' disjoint path still doesn't ensure that (a,u) and (v, b) are disjoint.

Comment: i see, I still don't know the ans, but I am thinking this. bi-comp means for every pair of vertices, there is a circle containing them. And it seems no matter how the two circle containing a, b and u, v intercept, there is always a path satisfying requirement.

Comment: @PetarPetrovic I tried make cycle which includes a, u, v and it seems always possible to make such cycle because any 2 edge lies on some cycle in same bi-comp, so (a, x) (u, v) should. Then If b is on that cycle, the solution is obvious. If not, then b should have at least 2 path to that cycle(otherwise not biconnected). Then tried many possible situations and it seems that can always make the (a->(u,v)->b) path. But.. idk this is right.. Btw, tried to inductive proof using H-path but also failed :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_decomposition says that a graph is biconnected iff it has an ear decomposition.  I think this will make a proof by induction on the number of ears pretty clear (though you have a few combinations of cases to handle -- A and B in the same ear vs. different ears; E between them vs. "to one side" as a subcase of the first case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biconnected means that you can remove any vertex v and any pair of vertices will remain connected ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_graph)).

So let's assume the statement it's not possible.
That means that we have two paths A to u and v to B that have to share at least one vertex (call it x). But that means that if I remove x from the biconnected component then either you can't connect A to u or v to B. But both pairs are part of the biconnected component so we have a contradiction.

Comment: can you elaborate on why the statement is false implies two paths A to u and v to B that have to share at least one vertex? thanks.

Comment: But there are 2 independent paths from A to u AND v to B so there are at least 4 combinations. So just removing x seems not to disconnect the graph..

Comment: @PetarPetrovic The inverse statement is that there are biconnected components where you can't have a simple path A-E(u,v)-B. So if the path is not simple then there are repeating vertices.

Comment: @hamtory That's the point. When you assume the statement is false you reach a logical contradiction (I reach a statement that contradicts the original conditions, that the vertices belong to the same biconnected component). That means the original statement has to be true. This is proof by negation.

Comment: @sorin I mean what if there is another path that shares y so that just removing x does not disconnects the graph. But after drawing all those cases realized that then there IS path from A to B so(those x, y are act like warp hole). Thanks for reply!

Comment: What does "That means that we have two paths A to u and v to B that have to share at least one vertex (call it x)" mean?  The mere *existence* of a pair of paths (one from A to u, the other from v to B) that share some vertex x does not imply the contradiction you need.  Under the assumption that the claim is false, it's true that *every* pair of paths (one from A to u, the other from v to B) must intersect in at least one vertex, but this could be a different vertex for every such pair -- nothing (in the arguments that you have so far given) forces it to be the same vertex x.